# How to trigger an update of Shiny's dataTable output

Tags: r, shiny-server, shiny

I'm lost somewhere between Shiny's concept of reactives, conductors and oberservers.
I followed [this](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/reactivity-overview.html) example about reactivity and [this](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/persistent-data-storage.html) example about persistent data storage.

I am building a shiny app with two (or more) tabPanels. The first tab allows the user to upload some csv-files, which are then analyzed and displayed as plots. In the second panel I would like to let the user explore the dataTable which is calculated in the same step.

However, the dataTable output is only updated the first time this view is opened. This means, if the user clicks on this tab before doing the calculations, he won't see anything, since there are no results yet. If he then comes back after the calculation is finished, the table will still be empty. If he does the calculation first and then clicks on the *Results*-tab, he will see the correct output. But if he decides to go back and recalculate, the dataTable output is again not being updated.

To be more precise, *output$results* is only being executed **exactly once**, when the view is opened for the first time, regardless of any future changes to the table that is displayed.

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  createPlots <- reactive ({ 
    numberOfFiles <- length(input$files$datapath) 
    for (i in 1:numberOfFiles) {
      local({
        my_i <- i
        plotname <- paste("plot", my_i, sep="")

        File <- read.csv(input$files$datapath[my_i])

        output[[plotname]] <- renderPlot({
          result <- runDensity(File, f)
          saveData(result$counts)
          plot(result$data, main=id, pch=19,cex=0.2, col= ColoursUsed[result$clusters])
        })
      })
    }
  })

  output$densityPlot <- renderUI({

    inFile <- input$files
    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)
    createPlots()
    numberOfFiles <- length(inFile$datapath) 
    plot_output_list <- lapply(1:numberOfFiles, function(i) {
      plotname <- paste("plot", i, sep="")
      plotOutput(plotname)
    })

    do.call(tagList, plot_output_list)
  })

  output$results <- renderDataTable({
    loadData()
  })

  saveData <- function(data) {
    data <- as.data.frame(t(data))
    if (exists("responses")) {
      responses <<- rbind(responses, data)
    } else {
      responses <<- data
    }
  }

  loadData <- function() {
    if (exists("responses")) {
      responses
    }
  }
```

I tried making the variable *responses* reactive at different positions in the code, without success. If I do it globally, outside of the shinyServer function, I create an infinite loop of *createPlots()*

```
responses <<- NULL
makeReactiveBinding("responses")
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
...
})
```

Inside the *output* or *loadData* functions, it didn't have an effect at all. How else can I trigger an update of the output function?

**Edit**

[Here](https://benedikt.shinyapps.io/example) is a minimal working example on shinyapps.io

Comment: it would be best if you could provide a minimally reproducible example of the app (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), a number of your UDFs are not shown here and it would be nice to see the ui.R

Comment: I added a link to a working example. I thought the server side might be sufficient for this question, but you're right - it's always better to the whole picture.